# Allways 7 countdown on page(7 divs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

How can I make that there are always 7 divs(countdowns) on the page? I programmed this countdown for now there are just 2 of them but I will add around 30 more. How can I make that there are always 7 countdowns on the page.

Example: One countdown is finished and removed from the page automatically and another one is added to the bottom automatically.

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
if(n == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5){
var timer1;
function cdtd1() {
    var sad1 = new Date();
    var dolazak1 = new Date(sad1.getFullYear(),sad1.getMonth(),sad1.getDate(),14,52,00);
    var timeDiff1 = dolazak1.getTime() - sad1.getTime();
    if (timeDiff1 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer1);
        $('#dani1Box').remove();
        $('#sati1Box').remove();
        $('#minute1Box').remove();
        $('#sekunde1Box').remove();


    }
    var sekunde1 = Math.floor(timeDiff1 / 1000);
    var minute1 = Math.floor(sekunde1 / 60);
    var sati1 = Math.floor(minute1 / 60);
    var dani1 = Math.floor(sati1 / 24);
    sati1 %= 24;
    minute1 %= 60;
    sekunde1 %= 60;

    $("#dani1Box").html(dani1);
    $("#sati1Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati1 + ':');
    $("#minute1Box").html(minute1 + ':');
    $("#sekunde1Box").html(sekunde1);

    timer1 = setTimeout(cdtd1, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd1();
});

var timer2;
function cdtd2() {
    var sad2 = new Date();
    var dolazak2 = new Date(sad2.getFullYear(),sad2.getMonth(),sad2.getDate(),23,45,00);
    var timeDiff2 = dolazak2.getTime() - sad2.getTime();
    if (timeDiff2 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer2);
        $('#dani2Box').remove();
        $('#sati2Box').remove();
        $('#minute2Box').remove();
        $('#sekunde2Box').remove();

    }
    var sekunde2 = Math.floor(timeDiff2 / 1000);
    var minute2 = Math.floor(sekunde2 / 60);
    var sati2 = Math.floor(minute2 / 60);
    var dani2 = Math.floor(sati2 / 24);
    sati2 %= 24;
    minute2 %= 60;
    sekunde2 %= 60;
    $("#dani2Box").html(dani2);
    $("#sati2Box").html('6-Sopot ' + sati2 + ':');
    $("#minute2Box").html(minute2 + ':');
    $("#sekunde2Box").html(sekunde2);

    timer2 = setTimeout(cdtd2, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd2();
});
}
</script>





<style type="text/css">
#dani1Box, #sati1Box, #minute1Box, #sekunde1Box, #dani2Box, #sati2Box, #minute2Box, #sekunde2Box{
         font-size:70px;
         color:#1f62a7;
         font-family:Sans-serif;
         display: inline-block;
}







</style>
  <center>
    <div>
    <div id="sati1Box"></div>
    <div id="minute1Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde1Box"></div>
    </div>

<h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:15px;">&nbsp;</h1>

    <div>
    <div id="sati2Box"></div>
    <div id="minute2Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde2Box"></div>
    </div>

   </center> 
</body>
```

Comment: This: `if(n == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5){` will always evaluate to true because `2` is considered "truthy" in JavaScript. You can't compare `n` against multiple values like that. You need to do `if(n == 1 || n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 4 || n == 5){`.

Comment: Alternatively to Anthony's way, you could do `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].indexOf(n) !== -1` or if you can assume an integer, `n > 0 && n < 6`